# Create a checkered background using CSS

Tags: css

Why can't you create a checkered background using something like this?

```
background-color:#ccc;
background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, #aaa 50%),
                 linear-gradient(90deg, #aaa 50%, #ccc 50%);
background-size:50px 50px,50px 50px;
background-position:0 0, 0 25px;
```

The idea is to layer the alternating colors on the bottom of a striped square. It doesn't work but it seems like it should.

Comment: http://lea.verou.me/demos/css3-patterns.html

Answer (score 25):

Here is an exact replica of what a checkered background looks in a graphic design editor like Photoshop or Illustrator. (ALL CSS)

```
.checkered{
    height: 240px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0), white;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0), -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0), white;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0), linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0), white;
    background-repeat: repeat, repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0, 5px 5px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    -webkit-background-origin: padding-box, padding-box;
    background-origin: padding-box, padding-box;
    -webkit-background-clip: border-box, border-box;
    background-clip: border-box, border-box;
    -webkit-background-size: 10px 10px, 10px 10px;
    background-size: 10px 10px, 10px 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1);
    transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1);
}
```

You can see a working example in my pen [**here**](https://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/jabwZd)

Answer (score 13):

This implementation yields a checkered background on Chrome, Firefox and Safari:

```
body {
    background-image:
      linear-gradient(45deg, #000 25%, transparent 25%),
      linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #000 75%),
      linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #000 75%),
      linear-gradient(45deg, #000 25%, #fff 25%);    

    background-size:100px 100px;       

    background-position:0 0, 0 0, -50px -50px, 50px 50px;
}
```

This style defines a four part background image.  Each linear-gradient defines a black triangle.  The triangles are shifted so that they align to form squares (two triangles each).  The last linear-gradient defines the color of the other two squares (the negative space).  The positioning of the third and fourth triangle is what makes it work.  (They would otherwise be positioned on top of the other two similar styles.)   See the result in the fiddles provided (for a better understanding replace #000 with four different colors and change #fff to transparent):

http://jsfiddle.net/1o0f34hp

Applied to a div:
http://jsfiddle.net/1o0f34hp/1

However there does seem to be some tearing along the edges between triangles in the Firefox.  This artifact is referenced here:

[background image, linear gradient jagged edged result needs to be smooth edged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091401/background-image-linear-gradient-jagged-edged-result-needs-to-be-smooth-edged)

I've also implemented this as a React styled-component as follows:

```
let dark = '#777';
let light = '#ccc';

export const Checkerboard = styled.div`
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, ${dark} 25%, transparent 25%),
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, ${dark} 75%),
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, ${dark} 75%),
    linear-gradient(45deg, ${dark} 25%, ${light} 25%);

  background-size: ${props => `${props.size} ${props.size}`};

  background-position: 0 0, 0 0,
    ${props =>
      `calc(${props.size} / -2) calc(${props.size} / -2), calc(${
        props.size
      } / 2) calc(${props.size} / 2)`};
`;
```

Comment: This answer helped! Also I added a small touch of CSS variables: http://jsfiddle.net/4eds0ybg/

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of playing around and trying to do this in other ways I actually understood what you wanted to do :-). And you were actually very close. You had one single problem: Both your gradients have `90deg`, so they covered each other. Also there's no need for the background color since the gradient in the back does not have any transparency and it covers everything.

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-image:linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 50%, #aaa 50%),
                 linear-gradient(90deg, #aaa 50%, #ccc 50%);
background-size:50px 50px,50px 50px;
background-position:0 0, 0 25px;
}
```

Also see this great post for how to create a proper checkerboard: http://lea.verou.me/2011/02/checkerboard-pattern-with-css3/

Comment: I saw that article by lea and that is what I was trying to get, but it seemed like there should be a simpler way.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I came up with is to use `conic-gradient()`. This also avoids the artifacts produced by `linear-gradient()` with `45deg`.

```js
function setVar(name, value) {
  document.getElementById('checkered').style.setProperty(name, value);
}
```

```css
.checkered {
  --color-1: #808080;
  --color-2: #a9a9a9;
  --size: 8px;
  
  background-image: conic-gradient(var(--color-1) 25%, var(--color-2) 25%, var(--color-2) 50%, var(--color-1) 50%, var(--color-1) 75%, var(--color-2) 75%);
  background-size: calc(var(--size)*2) calc(var(--size)*2);
}

input {
  margin: 4px;
  height: 32px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Checkered Background Image (Pure CSS)</title>
</head>

<body style="margin:0; width:100vw; height:100vh;">
  <div id="checkered" class="checkered" style="width:100%; height:100%; padding: 20px; box-sizing:border-box; display:flex; align-items:start;">
    <div style="background-color:white; padding:8px; border-radius:9px; display:flex;">
      <input type="color" name="color-1" value="#808080" oninput="setVar('--color-1', this.value)">
      <input type="color" name="color-2" value="#a9a9a9" oninput="setVar('--color-2', this.value)">
      <input type="number" name="size" min="1" value="8" oninput="setVar('--size', this.value + 'px')">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I made this simplified version.  Set color & size in root properties in CSS.

```css
:root {
    --checker-color-1: #abcedf;
    --checker-color-2: #123456;
    --checker-size: 20px;
    --checker-gradient: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--checker-color-1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, var(--checker-color-1) 75%);
}

body {
    background-color: var(--checker-color-2);
    background-image: var(--checker-gradient), var(--checker-gradient);
    background-position: 0 0, var(--checker-size) var(--checker-size);
    background-size: calc(var(--checker-size) * 2) calc(var(--checker-size) * 2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS Checkered Background</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**Updates:**

This snippet was derived from [CSS Checkered Background](https://codepen.io/sassano/pen/BaLgbpv) which shows a few more options.

But I have also since learned a new way of achieving the same effect, but it uses SVG (as well as JavaScript to create the SVG) [SVG Checkered Background](https://codepen.io/sassano/pen/WNRaKXX).  Each method though has its own caveats.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another tweak on this design but on a bias.

Please note that the background-size is important to keep a smooth transition in this pattern.

```
html {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background:repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,64,101,0.7) 40%, #004065 60%),
       repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0,80,126,0.7) 40%, #004065 60%);
    background-size:12px 18px;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

To change the color of the background, alter the second hex color in both repeating linear gradients.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 2):

While the previous answers show that it is possible, in most cases it's probably better to use an actual background image.

A 10x10 PNG checker image is around 80 bytes.
That is 108 bytes base64-encoded, and 148 bytes for the complete CSS rule - less than the shortest pure-CSS solution.
A 2x2 PNG image is not much smaller, but needs additional CSS for scaling and rendering.

Comment: Good to always keep in mind!

Answer (score 1):

I made a checkerboard pattern based on 10x10 squares in the Terminal with **ImageMagick** like this:

```
magick -size 10x10 xc:"gray(154)" xc:"gray(102)" +append \( +clone -flop \) -append -strip checkerboard.png
```

That looks like this:

[image]

Now, if I want the base64 representation I can do:

```
magick -size 10x10 xc:"gray(154)" xc:"gray(102)" +append \( +clone -flop \) -append -strip png:- | base64
```

That gives this:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAAAAACo4kLRAAAAH0lEQVQY02OcxQADZ+AsJgYsYKgIsiD8YTJInEShIAA1NwKQeKc4/QAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

which is just 120 characters!!!

Then I can use that for the repeating background like this:

```
<div style="background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAAAAACo4kLRAAAAH0lEQVQY02OcxQADZ+AsJgYsYKgIsiD8YTJInEShIAA1NwKQeKc4/QAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==)">'
```

And if I put a red `<img>` with a gradient transparency, on that background, I get:

[image]

Comment: Mark, there is already a checkerboard pattern in Imagemagick that you can modify and then tile. See checkerboard: at https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#builtin-patterns

Comment: @fmw42 Yes, thank you... but this is tiled *by the browser* using HTML/CSS so that transparent images show up on a checkerboard background on the web without the server having to composite them.

Comment: Note that this answer is an actual implementation of @handle 's suggestion.