# background image, linear gradient jagged edged result needs to be smooth edged

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-shapes, linear-gradients

I'm trying to make the bottom of an image pointed. I've tried to get this effect by producing two triangles at the bottom. They must be responsive. and after searching all over the internet with a lot of examples that don't work for my requirement this is the best so far I've managed to produce.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%
}
.image {
  width: 1410px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.pointer {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.triangleWrapper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.lefttriangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #ffffff 50%, transparent 50%);
}
.righttriangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left top, #ffffff 50%, transparent 50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/1410/500">
  <div class="pointer">
    <div class="triangleWrapper">
      <div style="height: 100%;" class="lefttriangle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="triangleWrapper">
      <div style="height: 100%;" class="righttriangle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/richyrb/pen/dYzmvq/)

It works exactly how I want it to as it is responsive without the need for media queries. BUT it has a jagged edge on the triangle line that isn't 90deg.

How do I get this to produce a smooth line in most if not all modern browsers? I'm not asking for backward compatibility.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Unfortunately, this always happens when we use angled `linear-gradient` images and currently the only way to overcome this behavior seems to be to **avoid hard-stopping** of the colors (that is, don't make the stop point of one color as the start point of the next). Making the **second color start a little farther away from the stop point of the first color** would kind of create a blurred area and make it look more smoother. This is still not 100% perfect but is better than having jagged edges.

```css
.lefttriangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #ffffff 48%, transparent 50%); /* note the change of stop and start points */
}
.righttriangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left top, #ffffff 48%, transparent 50%);  /* note the change of stop and start points */
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%
}
.image {
  width: 1410px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.pointer {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.triangleWrapper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.lefttriangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #ffffff 48%, transparent 50%);
}
.righttriangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left top, #ffffff 48%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/1410/500">
  <div class="pointer">
    <div class="triangleWrapper">
      <div style="height: 100%;" class="lefttriangle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="triangleWrapper">
      <div style="height: 100%;" class="righttriangle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Alternate Implementations:**

**Clip Paths**: You can use `clip-path` feature also to produce a similar effect. The advantage of using `clip-path` is that it is both responsive and also produces a transparent cut. [The SVG based `clip-path` has better browser support than the CSS version](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path). This is not yet supported in IE though.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%
}
.image {
  width: 1410px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.css-clip {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 90%, 50% 100%, 100% 90%, 100% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 90%, 50% 100%, 100% 90%, 100% 0%);
}
.svg-clip {
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipper);
  -moz-clip-path: url(#clipper);
  clip-path: url(#clipper);
}
```

```html
<!-- CSS Clip-path - Lower browser support -->
<div class="image css-clip">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/1410/500">
</div>

<!-- SVG Clip-path - Better browser support -->

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="clipper">
      <path d="M0,0 0,0.9 0.5,1 1,0.9 1,0z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div class="image svg-clip">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/1410/500">
</div>
```

**Using CSS Transform:** You could also try using the approach mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368404/how-to-create-a-polygon-shape-div-with-css/30370429#30370429). It achieves a pointed effect on the left side but it should be easy to adapt it to create a pointed effect on the bottom side.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%
}
.image {
  width: 1410px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.top-container,
.bottom-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.top-container {
  left: 0px;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  transform: skewY(10deg);
}
.bottom-container {
  right: 0px;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
  background-position: 0% 100%;
}
.top-container:after,
.bottom-container:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -62px;  /* tan(10) * (width/2) / 2 */
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/1410/500);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
}
.top-container:after {
  left: 0px;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
}
.bottom-container:after {
  right: 0px;
  transform: skewY(10deg);
  background-position: 100% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class='top-container'></div>
  <div class='bottom-container'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Harry, I will look at the CSS Transform route, the clip path works good but i still need IE support :( I will update this Q&A once i've produced the results i need.

Comment: Harry i've played with the transform code that was suggested in the link you provided. see [link](http://codepen.io/richyrb/pen/pjrQRb) do you have any further recommendations as it hasn't produced a clean line like their snippets.

Comment: actually it has in chrome. but not safari.. any anti analysing fix for safari on this?

Comment: @user3072439: Please refer to the snippet that I have added just now into the answer (the last one). It should work in all browsers and if it doesn't then I am afraid there is no option other than clip-path.

Comment: Harry, i get the results needed. fantastic. BUT the solution isn't flexible for CMS so if an image change is required then CSS would need to be edited everytime. I know this wasn't in the original Question brief but i feel if we are looking for an elegant solution for the majority of users then a more flexible management of content would be required. because the image is now in the &:before &:after pseudo its not even a case of adding it inline on the #image tag.

Comment: rather than the left and right containers now been screwed at the top and containing the image can they not be the white triangles at the bottom?

Comment: @user3072439 The pseudo element usage is just to reduce the clutter. If you feel that is making it inflexible then you can add an extra child tag to the inner `div` elements and apply the styles to that. I don't really like the white triangle option because it makes in inflexible and not much use for other users who may have a non-solid color background.

Comment: For me 48% and 50% were too blurry, since I tried to get a straight line.
49.9% and 50.1% worked fine. But when looking for perfection your eye will see this tiny cut off at the edges.

Comment: Thank you! I used 49.99% and 50% worked fine for me. 49.9 showed a slight blur this seems clean enough

Answer (score 26):

Just found an insanely good solution on codepen using `calc(50% - 1px)`

https://codepen.io/hellonico/pen/xEYXmL

```
background: linear-gradient(7deg, currentColor calc(50% - 1px), transparent 50%);
```

No blur whatsoever, just a smooth edge

EDIT: .. apparently not in Safari?..

Comment: Nice one but that calc trick isn't producing a better output for the snippet used in this question. So, it seems like we should use whichever one fits our particular case.

Comment: I had issues using calc(50% - 1px) in Safari and Edge, as well. I've seen some resolutions, but honestly just doing 49.9% looked great in all browsers.

Comment: tested in firefox and calc looks better them .9%