# Add triangle to top of div with background image in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a point/triangle to my div with a background image but am struggling with how to create enough empty space.

Here's what I'm going for:

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

```
<div class="bg"></div>

.bg {
  position: relative;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/W27LCzB.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 200px;
}

.bg:before {
  content:'';
  border-left: 50px solid #fff; 
  border-right: 50px solid #fff; 
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent; 
  position:absolute; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 0;
}
```

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343018/div-with-triangle-at-the-bottom-with-background-image) Stack Overflow question, but the approach in the top answer creates borders that come from the ends of the rectangular div.

Comment: want to try html,css style triangle? try this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could achieve your design using another div. Hope you'll like it :)

```css
.bg {
  position: relative;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/W27LCzB.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 200px;
}

.bg:before {
  content:'';
  border-left: 50px solid #fff; 
  border-right: 50px solid #fff; 
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent; 
  position:absolute; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 0;
}

.helper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.helper:before, .helper:after {
  content: "";
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: calc(50% - 50px);
}

.helper:before {left: 0;}
.helper:after {right: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="helper"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want by using pseudo element and skew them to get the shape border

```css
.bg {
  position: relative;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/W27LCzB.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bg:before {
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: calc(50% + 20px);
  width: 150%;
  height: 50px;
  transform: skewX(-40deg);
}

.bg:after {
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: calc(50% + 20px);
  width: 150%;
  height: 50px;
  transform: skewX(40deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: @ItayGanor is that what he really want?

Comment: Yes. See the red sktech, the triangle is also red, which means it should be the image inside. That's the challenge.