# Ugly edge when using gradient

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a 2 coloured background to use it as the background for my text container. To get two different colours I've used a gradient. Let me show you what it looks like now.

[image]

If you look closely, you can see the line in the middle looks kind of, I don't know what to call it, lets just say it doesn't look smooth.

Here's my css:

```
.btn {
    background:#8a8a8a;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #000000 50%, #8a8a8a 50%);

    display:inline-block;
    padding:0.75em 2.0em;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0.25em 0;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: This is a known item. There is nothing wrong with your code. It is just how it behaves. Give a small gap between the two color stops points (like 49.5% and 50.5%). That helps in a lot of cases. In some other cases, adding a `backface-visibility: hidden` helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [background image, linear gradient jagged edged result needs to be smooth edged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091401/background-image-linear-gradient-jagged-edged-result-needs-to-be-smooth-edged)

Comment: @harry This helped thanks a lot! The small gap did the trick. I also tried making it 600x600 px and the hard edges disappeared  then aswel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving a small gap between the two color stops points (like 49.5% and 50.5%) did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this style here: https://jsfiddle.net/dnn02d64/4/

```
.btn {
    background:#8a8a8a;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #000000 49.99%, #8a8a8a 50.99%);

    display:inline-block;
    padding:0.75em 2.0em;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0.25em 0;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
```