# Staircase effect (jagged edges) on angled background linear-gradient only in OS X

Tags: html, css

[image]

This screen is part a stage of [this live page](http://cubesports.de/fitness).

All I do is make a background with linear-gradient, with an angle and two colors (mostly second color is transparent) with no gradient at all.

The issue doesn't occur on Windows. It seems to only occur on my Mac OS X Browers. (Chrome 53, Safari 9.1.2, Firefox 49 on Mac OS X 10.11.6, MBPr 15'' late 2013)

```
background: linear-gradient(7deg, @color1 50%, transparent 50%);
```

**I am not looking for a completely different approach to implement the angled lines**

I am curious if there is something I can do to get rid of the `linear-gradient` stair cases in Mac OS X browsers.

Comment: This is known to happen (not just in OS X but others also) when using angled linear gradients with hard stops. Try the approach mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091401/background-image-linear-gradient-jagged-edged-result-needs-to-be-smooth-edged/33094994#33094994

Comment: Well, .. but this is exactly what I do NOT want. I need the straight line there–
And the clip-path solution is what I had before but switched to linear-gradient backgrounds of clip-paths bad support.

Comment: Using color stop points just a little apart wouldn't spoil the effect. Instead of having `linear-gradient(7deg, @color1 50%, transparent 50%)`, try using `linear-gradient(7deg, @color1 49.9%, transparent 50.1%)`. It should be smoother (still not perfect) and should still be a line instead of staircase effect.

Comment: I immediately tried that, but I'm looking for perfection and with this tiny gradient you receive hard corners at the edges. It is really not much, but just not perfect :'( – But I guess I'll have to accept this is as good as it gets. Why don't you make an answer out of this comment where you point out the other SO-thread and your 49.9 and 50.1 solution and I'll set this as the answer.

Comment: I hope somebody will be able to help you but as far as I know perfection cannot be achieved currently with angled linear gradients. I didn't post an answer because it is way too close a solution to the other one and it would look like rep-hunting by posting similar answers. I shouldn't be telling this but if you feel that helped even a bit then you could upvote that one :)

Comment: good point. Didn't know the term "jagged edges" – Otherwise I would've found your referred thread. Unfortunately I can only flag it as a duplicate? Could you confirm it since you have so much reputation?

Comment: Sure mate, will mark it as a dupe now :) You can only flag but since I have a gold badge in CSS, I can close it. (*Edit:* I didn't realize this new change had kicked in and that question owners can also close it when they accept the suggestion.)

Comment: Shithell, I love SO 8) –

Comment: Just found another solution, which works golden! Can we open it again? ^^

Comment: Did you find the other solution also on SO? If yes, give me the link and I'll close this as dupe of that (or) if you found it outside SO, I will reopen it and you can then add your solution as answer. Or, if your solution applies to the linked thread then you can answer there also.

Answer (score 0):

use

.myclass {
    background: @color; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(7deg, @color1 50%, transparent 50%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(7deg, @color1 50%, transparent 50%); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(7deg, @color1 50%, transparent 50%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(7deg, @color1 50%, transparent 50%); /* Standard syntax */
}

Comment: I can't see any difference to what I did except the `@color1` – and the issue doesn't occur because of `currentColor` – next time please explain your solution and maybe post code properly.